# How do I open a recycled file from cmd?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, recycle-bin

if you `DIR /a /b /s C:\$Recycle.Bin` You will find some regular files, and some that have been turned into "info files" that look like `$RT58F.png`. If you go into the explorer they are shown as their previous versions, but if you click on it, it gives you the option to "restore" it. I'm wondering if it is possible to display this file's restore option from the CMD? I've tried starting it, and I've tried using `explorer /select,Filename`. I'm out of ideas.

EDIT: I'm not sure whether this should be here or on StackOverflow. This is more of a systematic thing than a coding thing so I feel it should be here. Let me know!

Answer (score 2):

The Recycle Bin in Windows is a special folder and as such, restoring files from the command prompt is not possible.

It may be possible to copy the file manually to a place outside of the recycle bin though. The folder has more info on each file, for example, their full name and their original location.

In any case, you can try the command `start filename.ext` but if that doesn't work, try copying the file to a folder outside of the $Recycle.bin folder, such as c:\temp and try to open it from there.

Comment: I did that but it is encoded

Comment: yeah, so my first sentence applies then. Its not possible.

Comment: I was wondering if there was a way to open up the option to restore it? Like open the properties file of the origional?

Comment: Not from the commandprompt. You can type start . from the command prompt to open that location into explorer, but you still have to manually restore the file.